# Master - Master setup on Postgresql 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 + Pgpool II

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-10, pgpool

Does anybody have experience in configuring Pgpool II with Postgresql 10 on Ubuntu 18.04?

I am trying to setup Master - Master setup on Postgresql 10 + Ubuntu. I am trying to use Pgpool II

I will have two or more mater DB servers running on different IPs and my objective is synced with each other.

I am looking for an open-source solution/s Your thoughts, suggestion and experiences are kindly welcome. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Pgpool-II provides [statement based replication](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/41/en/html/runtime-config-running-mode.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-REPLICATION-MODE) that can be used to create a master-master setup with PostgreSQL. But it has some shortcomings, especially when it comes to achieving the atomic visibility of data because of the absence of cross node snapshot control in PostgreSQL.
So it is better to use built-in streaming replication and use Pgpool-II for load-balancing and failover.

But if you are interested in implementing the master-master setup with PostgreSQL, have a look at Postgre-XL (https://www.postgres-xl.org) or refer to the PostgreSQL documentation that has some info on the various types of replication that are possible
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html